# Golang bson structs - use multiple field names for a single field in json but only one for writing to the database

Tags: json, mongodb, go, struct, bson

I have a struct like this -

```
type Address struct {
    AddressLine1 string        `json:"addressLine1" bson:"addressLine1"`
    AddressLine2 string        `json:"addressLine2" bson:"addressLine2"`
    Landmark     string        `json:"landmark" bson:"landmark"`
    Zipcode      string        `json:"zipcode" bson:"zipcode"`
    City         string        `json:"city" bson:"city"`
}
```

Due to some compatibility issues between the previous build and the latest yet-to-be-released build, I want to make sure that if someone posts json data that decodes using this struct they should be able to use either 'zipcode' or 'pincode' as the field name in their json. But when this value is written to my database, the field name should only be 'zipcode'.

In short,

```
{
"city": "Mumbai",
"zipcode": "400001"
}
```

or

```
{
"city": "Mumbai",
"pincode": "400001"
}
```

should both appear inside the database as -

```
{
"city": "Mumbai",
"zipcode": "400001"
}
```

How do I allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have both fields as pointer to string:

```
type Address struct {
    AddressLine1 string        `json:"addressLine1" bson:"addressLine1"`
    AddressLine2 string        `json:"addressLine2" bson:"addressLine2"`
    Landmark     string        `json:"landmark" bson:"landmark"`
    Zipcode      *string       `json:"zipcode,omitempty" bson:"zipcode"`
    Pincode      *string       `json:"pincode,omitempty" bson:"zipcode"`
    City         string        `json:"city" bson:"city"`
}
```

As you may note we're using **omitempty** in the json tag, so if one of the fields is not present in the json it will be ignored as a **nil** pointer and it will not be present after *Marshal()* or *Unmarshal()*

**Edit**:

In this case all we have to do is implement the method `UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error` to satisfy the interface [Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler), the method `json.Unmarshal()` will always try to call that method and we can add our own logic after Unmarshal the struct, in this case we want to know if *pincode* is settled if it's we assigned to *zipcode*:
full example here: https://play.golang.org/p/zAOPMtCwBs

```
type Address struct {
    AddressLine1 string  `json:"addressLine1" bson:"addressLine1"`
    AddressLine2 string  `json:"addressLine2" bson:"addressLine2"`
    Landmark     string  `json:"landmark" bson:"landmark"`
    Zipcode      *string `json:"zipcode,omitempty" bson:"zipcode"`
    Pincode      *string `json:"pincode,omitempty"`
    City         string  `json:"city" bson:"city"`
}

// private alias of Address to avoid recursion in UnmarshalJSON()
type address Address

func (a *Address) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    b := address{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &b); err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    *a = Address(b) // convert the alias to address

    if a.Pincode != nil && a.Zipcode == nil {
        a.Zipcode = a.Pincode
        a.Pincode = nil // unset pincode
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that the field **Zipcode** has a bson tag and **Pincode** not, also we have to create an alias of type address to avoid calling UnmarshalJSON recursively

Comment: You're right. But if the post data contains 'pincode', I still want that the final field name in the db should be 'zipcode'.

Comment: Yeah, this seems be the way to go! Btw, even if we don't use *string and use omitempty, the field will be ignored right. Unless we Marshal or Unmarshal in which case it will exist but be empty. Am I understanding correctly? Thank you for your time to answer anyway!

Comment: I tried it and got the error - 
Duplicated key 'zipcode' in struct utility.Address

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Ops, it seems that your library doesn't allow duplicate **bson** fields, in this case we have to personalize our Unmarshal process. See the new **Edit**

Comment: Yes we use omitempty to ignore a field if it's empty, but because the zero value of a string is empty quotes "" it's better to use a pointer to know if the field is really empty just checking with **nil**

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response @yandry-pozo